# How to reset a C++ class in its own member function

Tags: c++

given a class `test` with a member function `reset` that is supposed to reset all member variables to the values given in the constructor.

```
class test
{
    int a1 = 1;
    int a2 = 4;
    .
    .
    .
    int a_n = 2;

    void reset()
    {
        //reset all a_n to initial values
    };
}
```

What is the most elegant way to do so? I know I can reset a class by re-instanciating it in a program that uses an object of that class. Is there a way to do this from inside the class too?

Answer (score 5):

If your type has a meaningful default constructor (which yours does, because of the default member initializers) and is move assignable then you can assign a default constructed instance to `*this` :

```
void test::reset() {
    // Create a default constructed instance of `test`
    //   and assign it to `*this`
    *this = {};
};
```

Demo : https://godbolt.org/z/1jWrjf

Answer (score 2):

I would not provide a `reset()` function, but would require users to write

```
foo = {};
```

That would be the most idiomatic way, I think.