# How to reset a C++ class which has not-copyable member

Tags: c++

I refer this [How to reset a C++ class in its own member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618815/how-to-reset-a-c-class-in-its-own-member-function) and here is a simple class.

```
class myclass
{
private:
    some data...
    std::mutex m_mutex;
public:
    void clear() {
        *this = {};
    }
}
```

I can't write code like this because std::mutex has a deleted copy assignment operator

Comment: So you can't do that. Write it manually.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<>` could work here

Comment: I dont think language will allow that, because what will happen to `const` members? they cant change values, how do you even reset it?

Comment: The answer to the question "what _should_ `myclass::clear` do if `myclass::m_mutex` is currently locked?" is important, and something that only you can answer, because only you know how `myclass` is actually meant to be used.

Comment: What does it mean to you to "reset" a `std::mutex`?   Make sure your answer is specified in ways that a `std::mutex` supports (e.g. it has member functions to do elements of your "reset").   Then implement that in your `clear()` function.

Comment: Note that the first thing `myclass::clear` needs to do is to lock the mutex, otherwise race-condition.  Then it need to reset/clear all the other data members.  Then unlock the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ we sometimes differentiate between "logical state" of object and "physical state". Logical state - is state of object as it is observable through its public API. Physical state - is how object represented in physical memory. `std::mutex` is usually NOT part of logical state, but rather exist only for internal "housekeeping", i.e. interthread access synchronization.
This can be evident in following simplified example:

```
class Test {
    int val = 10;
    mutable std::mutex m;
public:
    int getValue() const {
        std::lock_guard l(m);
        return val;
    }

    void setValue(int v) {
        std::lock_guard l(m);
        val = v;
    }
};
```

Here logical state of object is represented by variable `val`. We can even define equivalence operator as:

```
    bool operator ==(const Test& other) {
        return getValue() == other.getValue();
    }
```

But if we want to declare function `getValue()` as `const`, as it should be case for all getters, then we MUST declare mutex as `mutable`, elsewhere we will get compiler error, since its not possible to lock const mutex.

Usage of keyword `mutable` usually is good indication that variable is not part of logical state. But it is not always used, since it is not always necessary to properly declare constness of all functions.

Ok, now back to your question. If you want to reset "logical state" of your object, then you can define assignment operator, something like this for our example:

```
    Test& operator=(const Test& other) {
        setValue(other.getValue());
        return *this;
    }
```

And then you can do your reset function exactly as you wanted:

```
    void reset()
    {
        *this = {};
    }
```

But for this to work, you either need to use correct constness of all functions and variables, or define move assignment operator or use slightly different reset function:

```
    void reset()
    {
        Test t;
        *this = t;
    }
```

This is because `{}` is rvalue and it can't be passed by non-const lvalue reference, so we either need to use lvalue reference, thus defining move assignment operator, use const lvalue reference or pass lvalue to copy assignment operator.

Now, what if for some reason you need to reset "physical state" of object, not logical state. This is possible too, BUT you need to understand what you are doing, becasue "resetting" mutex is Undefined Behavior if this mutex is locked at the moment. Anyway, to reset physical state you just need to call destructor and constructor on same object. Destructor can be called directly, and to call constructor we can use "placement new". So this function will look like this:

```
    void physical_reset() {
        this->~Test();
        new (this) Test();
    }
```