# clear() method for resetting all class fields to their default values using *this = {} in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, this, assign

I have few years of commercial experience with C in embedded programming, but I am pretty new to C++, so I might be missing something in my logic.

**Context:**

This is possible to reset all fields of an object `a` to their default values by calling `clear()` method of class `A` implemented as `*this = {}`.
It gives exactly the same result as if using `a = A();`. The address of an object doesn't change using either way, so it is still the same object in case it'd be crucial for some case.

**Question:**

What are the real risks, drawbacks or pros of using one or the other way, especially when it comes to issues with memory usages during dynamic allocation?
Or are these solutions both equivalent in all matter?

```cpp
A a;
//(...)
a.clear();


/* Where: */ 
void A::clear()
{
  *this = {};
}
```

instead of

```cpp
A a;
//(...)
a = A();
```

**Example:**

I checked with following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    int a1{3};
    int b1{0};
    
    void clear()
    {
        *this = {};
    }
};
int main()
{
    cout << "Using a.clear():" << endl;
    {
    A a;
    cout << a.a1 << " " << a.b1 << " address: "<< &a << endl;
    a.a1 = 1;
    a.b1 = 2;
    cout << a.a1 << " " << a.b1 << " address: "<< &a << endl;
    a.clear();
    cout << a.a1 << " " << a.b1 << " address: "<< &a << endl;
    }
    
    cout << endl << "Using a = A():" << endl;
    {
    A a;
    cout << a.a1 << " " << a.b1 << " address: "<< &a << endl;
    a.a1 = 4;
    a.b1 = 5;
    cout << a.a1 << " " << a.b1 << " address: "<< &a << endl;
    a = A();
    cout << a.a1 << " " << a.b1 << " address: "<< &a << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Using a.clear():
3 0 address: 0x7ffc38d8e990
1 2 address: 0x7ffc38d8e990
3 0 address: 0x7ffc38d8e990

Using a = A():
3 0 address: 0x7ffc38d8e988
4 5 address: 0x7ffc38d8e988
3 0 address: 0x7ffc38d8e988
```

So as expected.

BR,
MW

Comment: This is opinion-based I think. `a = {};` or `a = A{};` is clear, and every C++ programmer should now what that does, `a.clear()` is not since `.clear()` could be implemented in a variety of ways. This also goes "against" the standard `.clear()` for containers which do not completely "re-initialize" the container.

Comment: It's not opinion based. The difference is very quantifiable. It is a lot cheaper to clear a few variables than, let's say allocate and clear new buffers, then a clear function definitely uses less resources and runs faster than a construction + a move.  There cannot be a case where a construction + a move will be cheaper than a clear(), they may cost the same, but never cheaper.  For best results, and less code written, make a clear() function, which the default constructor calls.  This is especially important on embedded devices, where stack space may be at a premium.

Comment: There was recently related question, which can have some merit for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74912106/how-to-reset-a-c-class-which-has-not-copyable-member

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are semantically equivalent. And you are correct you can't change the address of an existing object.

I don't see why you would write the `clear` method. It's uncommon and the `a = A{}` or `a = {}` is as simple and "clear" as you can get and everybody understands what that does.

Comment: This answer is only fine if your application has infinite resources _and_ the class only contains POD members, and no C-style arrays. Constructing an object requires at the minimum some stack space, and complex object may require heap memory allocation, even when defaut-constructed.

Comment: Hello bolov,
If a.clear() is used many times across the code and at some point it will be necessary to retain some information in the object over clear then it is simply possible by re-implementing the `A::clear()` method rather than changing every file using `a = A()`.

Comment: A good workaround when the class is too large to fit in stack space, is to declare a static default value (like `static myclass* myclass_default = new myclass;`), and then do `*this = *myclass_default` in your `clear` method.